# Where this dashboard IP is coming from or hitting to?

Tags: openstack-horizon

I am new in OpenStack and presently exploring it. We have an installation of Openstack Icehouse. Everything works fine ( few occasional bugs! ). I was just wondering where the dashboard public IP x.x.x.40 is coming from. I checked the following-

1. on controller the http server is bound to *management IP:80* and running as it should be.
2. the external interface of controller is assigned x.x.x.41 i.e the very next of dashboard ip
3. netstat -tuplen and ifconfig do not show anything like x.x.x.40

My question is where this IP is coming from or hitting to? Can anyone point out. Thank you very much for your time.